# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click' while trying to loop through XPATH tags in an array

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to write a bot using Selenium Python to play an online game of tic-tac-toe.  I've scraped the XPATHS of the squares and placed them in variables.  The bot is simple.  It's just supposed to click random squares.  I'll enhance the bot later.  Right now, I just want to click elements, and I'm getting stuck by this line of code:

`squares[random_square].click()`

I get an attribute error in the traceback. I understand strings can't invoke the click() method, and usually, I would have something like this:

```
pickSquare = WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, Tags.someSquare))
pickSquare.click()
```

But I've put all of my XPATH variables into an array that I need to iterate through, and I'm not sure how to use By and EC on an array as such.  Below is the code I have so far.

```
class TestCase_PlayGame():
    
    URL = "http://localhost:3000"
    
    @pytest.fixture
    def load_browser(self, browser):
        browser.get(self.URL)
        yield browser
    
    def test_playGame(self, load_browser):

        squares = [Tags.square1,Tags.square2,Tags.square3,
                   Tags.square4,Tags.square5,Tags.square6,
                   Tags.square7,Tags.square8,Tags.square9]
        
        clickedSquares = []
        random_square = randint(0,8)
        time.sleep(10)

        for i in clickedSquares:
            if i == random_square:
                self.test_playGame()
            else:
                clickedSquares.append(random_square)
        squares[random_square].click()
```

**UPDATE 1:** Below is the traceback.

```
self = <TestCases.TestCase_PlayGame.TestCase_PlayGame object at 0x000001DA3F4139D0>
load_browser = <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="324ff7dc-195c-4bdf-9ceb-84bf978dfc66")>

    def test_playGame(self, load_browser):

        squares = [Tags.square1,Tags.square2,Tags.square3,
                   Tags.square4,Tags.square5,Tags.square6,
                   Tags.square7,Tags.square8,Tags.square9]

        clickedSquares = []
        random_square = randint(0,8)
        time.sleep(10)

        for i in clickedSquares:
            if i == random_square:
                self.test_playTTT()
            else:
                clickedSquares.append(random_square)
>       squares[random_square].click()
E       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'

TestCases\TestCase_PlayGame.py:52: AttributeError
```

Comment: the error is because you click is being called on one of the strings that squares has in its list.   the list is being populated by string objects by referencing the Tags attributes that are strings.

Comment: I know that.  How do I fix that?

Comment: you need something that is clickable from the page.  I don't use selenium, but looks like you are trying to programmatically click the cell.  you will need to figure out how to access the element in selenium and figure out how to activate the click.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath(squares[random_square]).click() is probably what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to restructure your code to do something like this to get the right objects to use click() on an element:

```
# import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver

# create webdriver object
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# get geeksforgeeks.org
driver.get("http://localhost:3000/")
```

then have the code that loops waiting on on results and selecting the next thing to try  and when you are ready to find and click the element have code like this:

```
# get element
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, squares[random_square])

# click the element
element.click()
```

Comment: I did try that, and I got an error saying "driver has no attribute find_element_by_xpath."  I think this is because find_element_by_xpath is not longer supported.  That's why I have to use the By class.

Comment: ok, so I was a little off,  let me edit  the second block.

Comment: @Trevor have a look at the change

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a pair of parenthesis in expression.
Instead of

```py
WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, Tags.resultOh))
```

And

```py
WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, Tags.resultEx))
```

Try

```py
WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until((EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, Tags.resultOh)))
```

And

```py
WebDriverWait(load_browser, 10).until((EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, Tags.resultEx)))
```